# How to use fingerprint API in web pages(HTML)?

Tags: html, android-fingerprint-api

Everyone now knows, there is a Fingerprint API in Android API 23 onwards.

Which can do authentication through fingerprints, when we touch the sensor, it gives fingerprint data to the requiring **app**, and we can easily authenticate by matching the given fingerprint with one that is previously stored.

But,

I want my HTML page, which is designed for Mobile devices, to authenticate through fingerprints

For example: If I had a login page, it would show a dialog, asking the user to put their finger on fingerprint sensor, and if that matches with stored one, "Hooray! Login Successful!"

---

For this, I think we need something like an API, which would connect: fingerprint manager , Chrome and my webpage.
So that whenever I request a fingerprint authorisation, chrome readily asks for fingerprint of the user.

(If this question is 'broad' or 'irrelevant', let me know by comments. Also, if anyone has a rough sketch, feel free to comment that. :) )

Comment: This is a nice idea. A way to implement this could be to have an app which only serves the purpose of authentication. So your website opens the app, the app asks the user to authenticate using fingerprint and then the app returns to the website whether the authentication was successful or not. However, this won't be very secure as another app with the same package name could bypass this. I think with the rise of PWA's, direct support for web authentication using fingerprint could be added in the near future. A more direct method does not exist currently to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I think using native HTML and JS its quite not possible. If you can give an approach to do what you've mentioned i.e. to fire an app upon a web page load, and return isAuthenticationSuccessful boolean to web page itself, it would be nice. @Yashovardhan

Comment: you can use deep linking to open the relevant activity in your app from the website. After authentication is complete, your app could pass data using either a server or just use URL parameters to open the necessary URL with the user details. However, as I said this method won't be very secure and could be bypassable. I'd actually wait until fingerprint authentication support is brought to PWAs if not already.

Comment: "Wait" ..............

Comment: Well, I've clearly explained the method if you wish to do so. With the increase in popularity of pwa, I'd say these things would come pretty soon. But using fingerprint authentication directly in Chrome is not possible as of now. If you need anything more specific, you can leave a reply. I don't think I can help here anymore than what I've already did.

Comment: App Linking feature allows you to associate an app with a web domain you own.